# How to implement a custom "ConfigurationSection" with a nested "ConfigurationElementCollection" containing a custom "Element"

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, web-config, configuration-files

I am trying to implement a custom configuration section containing a collection of another custom element. The customer element contains some simple strings but also a collection of certificateReference.

I have only included one instance of <it2.jwtAuthorisation> for now in the web.config, but this should be able to have multiple.

The issue I'm having is when loading the configuration I get the following error:

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized element 'audience'.

Source Error:

Line 15:   <it2.AuthorisationSchemes>
Line 16:     <it2.jwtAuthorisation>
Line 17:       <audience aud="https://localhost" />
```

I have tried changing the classes several times but without any luck.

This is the **web.config** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="it2.AuthorisationSchemes" type="WebAPI.Authentication.Configuration.JWT.MultipleCertAuthorisationConfigurationSection, WebAPI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
    </configSections>
    <it2.AuthorisationSchemes>
        <it2.jwtAuthorisation>
            <audience aud="https://localhost" />
            <issuer iss="IT2" />
            <certificateSigningKeys>
                <certificateReference x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" findValue="IT2.AccessTokenSigningKey" />
            </certificateSigningKeys>
        </it2.jwtAuthorisation>
    </it2.AuthorisationSchemes>
</configuration>
```

This is the **MultipleCertAuthorisationConfigurationSection** definition:

```
public class MultipleCertAuthorisationConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
  {
    private const string authSchemes = "it2.jwtAuthorisation";
    [ConfigurationProperty(authSchemes, IsRequired = true)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(JWTAuthorisationCollection),
        AddItemName = "add",
        ClearItemsName = "clear",
        RemoveItemName = "remove")]
    public JWTAuthorisationCollection jwtAuthSchemes
    {
      get
      {
        JWTAuthorisationCollection jwtAuthorisationCollection =
    (JWTAuthorisationCollection)base[authSchemes];

        return jwtAuthorisationCollection;
      }
      set
      {
        JWTAuthorisationCollection jwtAuthorisationCollection = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the **JWTAuthorisationCollection** definition:

```
  public class JWTAuthorisationCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
  {
    public JWTAuthorisationCollection()
    {
    }

    public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
    {
      get
      {
        return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap;
      }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
      return new JWTAuthorisationElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
      return ((JWTAuthorisationElement)element).Issuer;
    }

    public JWTAuthorisationElement this[int index]
    {
      get
      {
        return (JWTAuthorisationElement)BaseGet(index);
      }
      set
      {
        if (BaseGet(index) != null)
        {
          BaseRemoveAt(index);
        }
        BaseAdd(index, value);
      }
    }

    new public JWTAuthorisationElement this[string Issuer]
    {
      get
      {
        return (JWTAuthorisationElement)BaseGet(Issuer);
      }
    }

    public int IndexOf(JWTAuthorisationElement jwtAuth)
    {
      return BaseIndexOf(jwtAuth);
    }

    public void Add(JWTAuthorisationElement jwtAuth)
    {
      BaseAdd(jwtAuth);
    }

    protected override void BaseAdd(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
      BaseAdd(element, false);
    }

    public void Remove(JWTAuthorisationElement jwtAuth)
    {
      if (BaseIndexOf(jwtAuth) >= 0)
      {
        BaseRemove(jwtAuth.Issuer);
      }
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
      BaseRemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void Remove(string issuer)
    {
      BaseRemove(issuer);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
      BaseClear();
    }
  }
```

This is the **JWTAuthorisationElement** definition:

```
public class JWTAuthorisationElement : ConfigurationElement
  {
    public JWTAuthorisationElement(AudienceProviderElement audience, IssuerProviderElement issuer,
      JWKSEndpointProviderElement jwksEndpoint, MultipleCertReferenceSigningKeyProviderElements certificateSigningKeys, AppSecretSigningKeyProviderElement appSecretSigningKey)
    {
      Audience = audience;
      Issuer = issuer;
      JWKSEndpoint = jwksEndpoint;
      CertificateSigningKeys = certificateSigningKeys;
      AppSecretSigningKey = appSecretSigningKey;
    }

    public JWTAuthorisationElement()
    {
    }

    private const string audience = "audience";
    [ConfigurationProperty(audience, IsRequired = true)]
    public AudienceProviderElement Audience
    {
      get
      {
        return this[audience] as AudienceProviderElement;
      }
      set
      {
        this[audience] = value;
      }
    }

    private const string issuer = "issuer";
    [ConfigurationProperty(issuer, IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public IssuerProviderElement Issuer
    {
      get
      {
        return this[issuer] as IssuerProviderElement;
      }
      set
      {
        this[issuer] = value;
      }
    }

    private const string jwksEndpoint = "JWKSEndpoint";
    [ConfigurationProperty(jwksEndpoint, IsRequired = false)]
    public JWKSEndpointProviderElement JWKSEndpoint
    {
      get
      {
        return this[jwksEndpoint] as JWKSEndpointProviderElement;
      }
      set
      {
        this[jwksEndpoint] = value;
      }
    }

    private const string certificateSigningKeys = "certificateSigningKeys";
    [ConfigurationProperty(certificateSigningKeys, IsRequired = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MultipleCertReferenceSigningKeyProviderElements), AddItemName = "certificateReference")]
    public MultipleCertReferenceSigningKeyProviderElements CertificateSigningKeys
    {
      get
      {
        return this[certificateSigningKeys] as MultipleCertReferenceSigningKeyProviderElements;
      }
      set
      {
        this[certificateSigningKeys] = value;
      }
    }

    private const string appSecretSigningKey = "appSecretSigningKey";
    [ConfigurationProperty(appSecretSigningKey, IsRequired = false)]
    public AppSecretSigningKeyProviderElement AppSecretSigningKey
    {
      get
      {
        return this[appSecretSigningKey] as AppSecretSigningKeyProviderElement;
      }
      set
      {
        this[appSecretSigningKey] = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

It gets loaded by the following function and this is where the error occurs:

```
public AuthorisationConfigurationFactory()
  : this(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("it2.AuthorisationSchemes") as JWT.MultipleCertAuthorisationConfigurationSection)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this after finding [Correct implementation of a custom config section with nested collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661544/correct-implementation-of-a-custom-config-section-with-nested-collections). The Answer was exactly what I was looking for and the linked blog post gave a detailed description with the code on how to do this.

It seems like another person in the comments had the same issue following the Microsoft example:

> The key for me here was setting CollectionType on the nested
> collection to ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap. Without it
> I kept getting Unrecognized element 'tunnel'

This was also the error I was receiving.